# How to achieve high precision when computing log2 in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, math, precision

I'm computing log2 for very large numbers

For example:

```
math.ceil(math.log2(pow(2,64)+1))
```

This should return `65`, however, it returns `64`, since `math.log2(pow(2,64)+1)` returns 64.0 with low precision

Any thoughts how to work around?

Comment: You will need a multi-precision number type if you need more than 53 bits in a floating point mantissa.

Comment: I think, [mpmath](http://mpmath.org/) library may be what you're looking for. Also, you can try [decimal](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html#module-decimal) module of standart Python library.

Comment: at least from your example the easiest way is to call `bit_length()` on the integer

Comment: Thanks James, I also found out yesterday that bit_length is the easiest.